# How to get the saved image URL in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the path of the saved image. I am running the code on my physical device. I can take the picture but even if I save the picture there is no way for me to get the URL of the picture that is saved.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.photoImageView.image = photo

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {



    }
```

Comment: Why you want to access the path in saving with error?

Comment: I want to access it anywhere!

Comment: You can access when you pick the image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo ` and can save in some of your variable. And I guess this can only be done when you again open the image which you saved and grab the path in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo `

Comment: Basically, I want to take the image and then send the URL of the image to another screen which can display the image. I *can* send the UIImage to the other screen too which might be the solution I choose.

Comment: So its better that you save the image in your DocumentDirectory path also where you can get the image and its URL and can send anywhere

Comment: You are  picking the image from gallery and again saving that in gallery, why?

Comment: I want to save it in the Photos Library which it is doing. It just does not give me the URL after it saves. I am not picking the image from library. I am saving a NEW image

Comment: It will not give the path AFAIK. You can use Photo Framework to get all images and uRLs but that will be a lot of work. You save in gallery and DD directory both and then use it

Comment: The above code that I have successfully saves it to the photo album. So, there is no easy way to get the URL of the image which is just saved in the photos album.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get like this way, you can get the whole lot of images for a particular folder like Albums from Photo Framework but not individual. You can get individual only by selecting that image and using in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Comment: Okay! Thanks! Yeah I don't want to select the image since the person is taking a picture and all I wanted was to send the image to the parent view. Anyways.. I will find something. Thanks!

Comment: So thats even simpler, just pass that image object to your other class controller

Comment: Although it has deprecated but `AssetsLibrary` seems to be your only option.

Comment: Instead of passing UIImage I am passing Data (NSData) which looks more cleaner the class. UIImage is a UI element and I don't want to mix it with my classes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Apple does not provide an API to select any kind of file like in android with the use of file manager. If u want to bring up an image in the application you need to open albums and choose the necessary pictures.
If you still want the concept of file manager as folders, sub-folders and files on your device, you will have to use iCloud storage as it provides the above mentioned directory system as you wish to have.